# Charge as a function of time in an RC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

In my professors notes, there is a function representing charge in terms of time, however there is absolutely no explanation to why this function holds true. It seems like he skipped the whole part on showing the workings on how he arrived at the function of maybe it does not seem so obvious to me. Here is the function:

$$q(t)=e^{-t/\tau}q(0)+\int^t_{0}e^{-(t-s)\tau}v(s)ds$$

First of all I do not even get where this $v(s)$ came from, it says on the notes $v(t)$ is some known input, but input of what I do not understand.

Can anyone kindly show me the derivation or any pdf file related to this function, which I am not able to understand myself at how my professor arrived at this function.

Comment: Did you leave out a C in front of the integral?

Comment: No there was no C on my notes.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on the answer given by Koustubh, we have the differential equation (explicitly writing $V$ as a given funtion of time)

$$\frac{Q}{C}+R\frac{dQ}{dt}=V(t)$$

which is just a first order differential equation whose closed form solution is what you want,

$$Q(t)=Q(0)e^{-t/RC}+C\int_0^t ds\, e^{(s-t)/RC}V(s)$$

So, in short, the "input" is the chosen battery voltage as a function of time.

Comment: I am sorry I kind of understand this but where does the variable “$s$” arise from? Could you also elaborate  alittle more on why the first differential relationship holds?

Comment: The first differential relationship is just the potential difference in the circuit expressed as a function of time it is simply the potential due to the charge in the capacitor i.e. Q/C and the potential difference maintained across the ends of a resistor i.e. IR. If you are wondering where does the resistance arise from it is the resistance due to the wires.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know in an RC circuit i.e. one consisting of both resistors and capacitors. The charge in the capacitor can be expressed as a function of time as :

$$\displaystyle{q(t) =CV(1-e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}) }$$

Where $C$ is the capacitance of the capacitor , $V$ is the potential difference across it and $\tau$ is the time constant which is equal to $RC$ , $R$ is the resistance. As for the derivation, here it is from my notes : In fact it is pretty easy to derive it. Just take a capacitor which is intially uncharged then at some time say t seconds after you started charging it, write expression for the current flowing through the circuit and then you can integrate ! Massage it with some mathematical manipulation and you will have the function [image: Source : Me]

Source : Me

Comment: You've derived the equation for the charge on a capacitor, initially uncharged and connected at time $t=0$ to a fixed pd with a resistor in series. This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: In my derivation pd is varying as it is v - (q/c) as q is varying with time.

Comment: $v-(q/C)$ is the pd across the resistor. But you are treating v itself as a constant, for example in your integration.